# Function callback while rendering page for FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The function that called while rendering a module.Also I read somewhere to use `Arrow` function but I believe arrow function already in form code, is it ?

```
onRemoveCard = item => {
    return () =>
        this.props.removeModal(
            'Remove Card',
            'Are you sure want to remove this card?',
        );
};
```

A render item component from the `FlatList`.

```
<CardTile
    onRemove={this.onRemoveCard(item)}
    subtitle={autoReoladBalance}
    addGiftCard={false}
/>
```

How can this should be stopped for call while I am rendering item?  It should be called `onPress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `this.onRemoveCard(item)` while passing props in `CardTile`, instead, you should pass reference like

```
<CardTile
  onRemove={this.onRemoveCard} /* passing reference instead of calling*/
  subtitle={autoReoladBalance}
  addGiftCard={false}
/>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Where is your argument for this method? I thinks params is missing

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `onRemove` method inside `CardTile` component, I believe when `CardTile` will call the method, `item` parameter will be passed. BTW `CardTile` is custom component right?

Comment: Adding to @PrasunPal  answer , for passing custom params, you can reinstantiate the  function declaration `onRemove={() => this.onRemoveCard(item)}`

Comment: @PrasunPal yes, it custom component method with 1 arguments.